# RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Unable to send on OpenMp Multithreading Application

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, rpc

I am trying to get NFS disk quotas via rpc protocol. By using OpenMP, i am creating parallel udp connections. The program runs without any error with 1 and 2 core. When i increase core number to 4, after a while program gives "RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Unable to send" error on "clntudp_create()" function, which is creating udp connection . I am using following code for this job.

```
/*
     * 0 -> True
     * 1 -> Couldn't resolve hostname
     * 2 -> Udp connection couldn't initiate
     * 3 -> Query couldn't run 
     * 4 -> Unknown error
     */
    long long int diskOfUser::getNfsQuota(string blockDevice, int uid)
    {
        //some address resolving operations
        int whereToSplit = blockDevice.find(':');
        if(whereToSplit == std::string::npos)  
            return 5;
        std::string host = blockDevice.substr(0, whereToSplit);  
        std::string path = blockDevice.substr(whereToSplit+1, blockDevice.size() - whereToSplit);
        char *pathToGo = new char[path.size()+1];
        strcpy(pathToGo,path.c_str());
        char *hostToGo = new char[host.size()+1];
        strcpy(hostToGo,host.c_str());

        //variable definitions
        struct getquota_args *gqArgs;               
        gqArgs = new struct getquota_args;
        struct getquota_rslt *gqRslt;               //quota result object
        gqRslt = new struct getquota_rslt;
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;             //udp connection address
        struct hostent *hp;                 
        struct timeval timeout, totTimeOut;         //timeout values
        CLIENT *client = NULL;                      //udp client
        int socket = RPC_ANYSOCK;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        timeout.tv_sec = 6;
        totTimeOut.tv_sec = 25;
        totTimeOut.tv_usec = 0;
        //try to resolve host
        if ((hp = gethostbyname(hostToGo)) == NULL)
        {
            delete pathToGo;
            delete hostToGo;
            return 1;                   //hostname couldn't resolve
        }


        /* Try to start UDP connection (Problematic part)*/
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port =  htons(875);
        memcpy(&server_addr.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
        server_addr.sin_port =  0;
        if ((client = clntudp_create(&server_addr, (u_long)100011, (u_long)1, timeout, &socket)) == NULL)
        {
            delete pathToGo;
            delete hostToGo;
            clnt_pcreateerror("error"); // gives the following error "RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Unable to send"
            return 2;                   //udp connection could not start
        }

        /* UDP connection created */
        //quota asking operations ...

    }
```

Is there any way to make this job thread safe?

EDIT: "RPC: Unable to send; errno = Bad file descriptor" clnt_sperror() function is giving this error. I am starting four process with one core separately, program is running with no error. But 1 process with 4 core is always blowing up.

ANSWER:

```
/* UDP connection oluşturuluyor */
        if ((client = clnt_create(hostToGo, (u_long)100011, (u_long)1, "UDP")) == NULL)
        {
                delete pathToGo;
                delete hostToGo;
                return 2;                                       //rquotad ile udp connection oluşturma işlemi başarısız oldu
        }
        /* UDP connection oluşturuldu */
        client->cl_auth = authunix_create_default();            //rpc authentication handle
        gqArgs->gqa_uid = uid;                                  //argumanlar set ediliyor
        gqArgs->gqa_pathp = pathToGo;
```

I reached my goal with clnt_create() function. It is thread safe alternative of clntudp_create(). But, on the server side rquota.d seralizing all the request and answering one by one. Because of this it is not fully optimize.

Comment: Neither `gethostbyname` nor `clntudp_create` are thread-safe. Either put them in named critical sections (`#pragma omp critical (foo) { ... }`) or look for thread-safe alternatives. Note that `gethostbyname` returns a pointer to static memory, therefore not only the call but also the code that uses the return value should be put in the critical section;

Comment: i added critical stuff on clntudp_create, but still same error, also i could not find any alternative, also u are right about gethostbyname but now i am just focusing on problematic part.